# Is Initial Catalog required using SqlConnectionStringBuilder in C#/SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

Is the Initial Catalog parameter required when creating an SQL connection string using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class?

I'm working with C# and want to create a generic method as part of a customized Database class that just connects to the server (not to any specific database; in another method I will assign a database to the connection, but want to just connect to the server so I can first check that the DB exists without having to provide the database name when the connection is created).

Comment: You could use the master database as the initial catalog. You would use it any way to check for the existence of the database you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the initial catalog to `master` and go from there - the [master database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx) will always be present and supports the operations you need.